# Printing out post data

Tags: python, parse-platform

i have a small script that reads and parse emails and check them against a database to assist me with resetting passwords,

unfortunately i have a bug and i can't seems to find it, currently i'm trying to visually check if there's a difference in the details (hopefully finding a pattern).

this is the relevant parts of the code:

```
def send_device_match_reset(username, email):
    return requests.post(
         'https://api.parse.com/1/requestPasswordReset',
        headers=parse_headers,
        data=json.dumps({
            'username': username.upper(),
            'email': email.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'),
            'code': '*********'
        })
    )
```

and

```
if user.has_key('emailAddress'):
if user.get('emailAddress') == email:
    reset_response = send_device_match_reset(username.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'), email.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
    print "response code", reset_response.status_code
    if reset_response.status_code != 200:
      log.error('send_device_match_reset failed with %s:%s'%(username,email))
      log.error('logging msg: %s'%(reset_response.text))
      log.error('email: %s'%(email.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')))
      log.error('username: %s'%(username.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')))
      return
    log.info('Recovered using verified email')
    return message_processed(message, 'RecoveredByEmail', user=user)
```

now i'm trying to figure out how to print the actual headers from the #1st section "data"
inside my "log.error" debug lines.

i've been trying a direct approach by doing:

```
log.error(requests.post);
```

or

```
log.error(requests.post(data));
```

but it doesn't work - and i don't know python good enough to understand why.

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: @APerson, it varies from memory pointers `(function post at 0x7f07b87ae848)` to generic `global name 'data' is not defined`, depends on what i try

Comment: It doesn't even reliably give the same error?

Comment: @APerson, it does - it gives a different error per attempt. i just gave a general idea of what i'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log.error(requests.post);` prints the function pointer
`log.error(requests.post(data));` prints the result of the function, since data ist defined globally -> error

Try `log.error(parse_headers)` since this variable seems to be defined globally, it should work for you.
However, I normally stringify my variables like '{0}'.format(var) to enure, that I am working with a string afterwards.

**EDITED:**

```
def send_device_match_reset(username, email):
    data = json.dumps({
            'username': username.upper(),
            'email': email.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'),
            'code': '*********'
        })
    log.error('sending: data = {0}'.format(data))
    return requests.post(
         'https://api.parse.com/1/requestPasswordReset',
        headers = parse_headers,
        data = data
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need the "DATA" post specifically and not the headers.